# Increase playback speed of flash videos

Tags: flash

Is there a general purpose solution to increase the speed of arbitrary (embedded) flash videos (Youtube, vimeo, etc)?

Comment: What are you asking - the performance or the actual playback speed? Please clarify.

Comment: The actual playback speed: play the movie twice as fast

Comment: I know you asked about flash videos, but Youtube's HTML5 player actually has a playback speed setting (the tool icon). It is there also at least on the larger '16:9' embedded version of the player. Whether HTML5 player is actually supported by the embedded videos depends on the embedding code. You can enable the HTML5 trial [here](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about arbitrary embedded Flash videos, but for YouTube, I used to use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vlc-for-youtube/ablmclcliiiegfmpbkfhnhipoejclmel) Chrome Extension that replaces the Flash player with a VLC player. Playback is much smoother.

Unfortunately this extension is not working at the moment, not until VLC fixes their Lua script. So now I use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vlc-4-youtube-beta/jldiailifbdkepgpcojllmkbakleicab), which basically enqueues the selected YouTube video into my current queue in VLC (it needs to be running or the extension will fail).

You can probably try alternative Flash players, like `gnash` or whatever, but they don't improve much at all. And people say they are still unreliable.